# Displaying database entries in Rails 4 with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display my database entries. Angular repeats list items but doesn't display any values. The entries database has a title column.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="EntryCtrl">
  <h2>Angular Display</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
        {{entry.title}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Coffee-script:

```
app = angular.module("Resume", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Entry", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/entries/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "GET"}})
]

@EntryCtrl = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->
  $scope.entries = Entry.get()
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix, I had to add:

```
    respond_to :json, :html
```

and:

```
    respond_with Entry.all
```

...to the controller.

Answer (score 4):

$resource.get is used for fetching single object instance:

```
$scope.entry = Entry.get({id:123}, callback);
```

and $resource.query is used for retrieving a collection:

```
$scope.entries = Entry.query();
```

Comment: The get/query issue was a bi-product of troubleshooting. Thanks for the clarification though.